# Redirect to the previous page(same page)with destroy method

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am creating a cancel order page where customers can click on the cancel button and the page will render "order canceled successfully" and stay on the cancel page with the button disabled.
I've googled and searched through it still not too sure how to achieve that.

My destroy method:

```
def destroy
  order.cancel
  redirect_to order_path(order.shopify_id), notice: 'Order cancelled'
end
```

My view:

```
</div>
  <%= link_to 'Cancel Here', order_path(@order.shopify_id), method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-danger ' %>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried :back? i.e. in controller

```rb
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to :back }
end
```

It will redirect to the page from where the request has arrived.

Comment: hi thanks for you reply! but it threw back undefined method "back"

Comment: @developing `:back` is a symbol not a method. Make sure you include the colon in front.

Comment: @engineersmnky is right. You need to use back as a symbol.  inline `:back `